# Why getting this "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed" error during Microsoft Graph API call?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const { GraphRbacManagementClient }  = require('azure-graph');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
   try{
        const credentials = await msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, clientSecret, tanent);
        const client = new GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, tenantId);
        const results = await client.users.list();

        context.res = {
           body: results
        };
   } catch (error) {
       console.log('error==> ',error);   // Getting error: Authentication_MissingOrMalformed
       context.res = {
           body: error
       };
   }
}
```

**I want to get all users list using azure graph sdk. But after calling the client.users.list() function I'm getting the error ("Authentication_MissingOrMalformed"). How do I fix this error and get all users list.**

**How to get all users list from Azure Active Directory using Azure Graph SDK (Nodejs) ?**

Comment: Did you try... reading the error message... and thinking about what it suggests?

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is missing `{ tokenAudience: 'graph' }`, please refer to my code:

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const { GraphRbacManagementClient }  = require('azure-graph');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try{
         msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret("clientId", "clientSecret", "tenantId", { tokenAudience: 'graph' }, function (err, credentials) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            const client = new GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, "tenantId");

            client.users.list((err, results, request, response) => {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log(JSON.parse(response.body).value.length);
            });
            
         });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error==> ',error);
        context.res = {
            body: error
        };
    }
}
```

After running the code above, if the number of users in your AD is greater than 100, it will output `100` because graph api can response 100 users in a page(default is 100).

==================================**Update**================================

Please check if you have added the permission to the application registered in Azure AD. If you didn't add the permission, please follow the below steps:

**1.** Go to the application which registered in your Azure AD (It's the application which you use its `clientId`).

**2.** Add the permission.

[image]

[image]

**3.** Click "**Grant admin consent for xxx**".
[image]

**4.** After a few minutes, run your code again.

Comment: l{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}

Comment: Hi @Param The error message means you don't have permission to do this operation. You need to add the permission, please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: @Param Did you run the code success ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: I'm really sorry to response you late. Actually I don't have the API permission that's why I'm getting the above error. I talked to Admin when I'll get permission as soon as I'll update you. Thank you once again !!